# Deploying to Heroku with untracked .env file

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am having trouble deploying my Django application on Heroku.

The problem occurs because I am using the [`python-decouple` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-decouple). I am using it so as not to expose my `API_KEYS`.

This is the error I am getting:

```
  File "/app/weather/settings.py", line 20, in <module>
    API_KEY = config('API_KEY')
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/decouple.py", line 197, in __call__
     return self.config(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/decouple.py", line 85, in __call__
    return self.get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/decouple.py", line 70, in get
    raise UndefinedValueError('{} not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.'.format(option))
decouple.UndefinedValueError: API_KEY not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.
```

I have stored all the variables in `BASE_DIR + '/.env'` file and added this file to my `.gitignore` file.

What is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to load settings from files that aren't tracked on Heroku. Its [filesystem is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem); anything you add to it manually will be lost the next time your dyno restarts. This [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting).

The "Heroku way" is to [put your settings in environment variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars). Environment variables will be available to all dynos, and have two major benefits:

- Your settings won't be exposed in your code repository
- You can change environment variables without making code changes

Happily, [`python-decouple` respects environment variables since version 3.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-decouple#overriding-config-files-with-environment-variables). You should be able to add environment variables for all of your settings and then deploy successfully. (I haven't used that library before, but it looks like you don't need an `.env` file if all of your settings are found in the environment.)